# How can I track state of different API calls in Redux?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-observable

Say I have an application for managing todos, the user can add new todos by clicking a button.
When the user clicks the button a spinner will appear until the todo is saved to the backend or the request fails.

When the button is pressend an action called *ADD_TODO_REQUEST* is dispatched, which will then be intercepted by a redux-observable epic that will perform an HTTP request to save the todo and will dispatch an *ADD_TODO_COMPLETE* action or an *ADD_TODO_FAILED* action depending on the HTTP request result.

The application should display a spinner next to the "add todo" button.
To do so my state contains a flag called *isSaving* that will be set to true when the HTTP request is pending and will be reset to false when the HTTP request completes.

My initial state shape looks like this:

```
{
     todos: [],
     isSaving: false
}
```

When the application starts the first action that will be dispatched is a *FETCH_TODO_REQUEST* which will call another API endpoint to get all the todos.

Once again the application should show a spinner to inform the user that the todos are being downloaded, to do so I've added another flag to the state called *isFetching*.
This new flag is needed because if I would share the same flag when adding todos I would display a spinner for the whole application when the user is simply adding a todo.

My initial state shape now looks like this:

```
{
     todos: [],
     isSaving: false,
     isFetching: false
}
```

This approach looks fine to me, but if the user can also delete todos I have to keep track of this additional HTTP request status, therefore I would need to add yet another flag (probably called *isDeleting*) to the state.

Note that I would like to show a spinner next to the "add button" and one spinner next to every todo that is being deleted. These spinners can all appear at the same time that's why one single flag is not enough and I have resorted to this approach.

In scenarios where I could potentially have many different concurrent API "actions" I would need a flag for every possible request.
If I also wanted to display errors I would now need two properties for every API "action" available: one to signal that the request is in progress and the other to hold the error object.

The problem with this approach is that it looks *very*, *very*, verbose.

Is there an idiomatic and smarter way to keep track of the status of concurrent http requests ?
Is it correct to have a flag for every possible http request that touches the same "entity" ?

Comment: It depends on how you want things to be displayed? You could use a common `isDoingSomething` flag but then all components which rely on this flag would display their loading state simultaneously.

Comment: @madebydavid I would like to have more than one spinner. For example: one next to the "add todo" that is visible only when the todo si added and one next to the todo that is being deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen many ways of handling this, all with their own pros and cons.

### Each resource has its own status

While there are no rules, it is commonly suggested that redux users model their state's schema as if it were a database.

That mostly means you'll store resources indexed by some ID. In this case, you've got a list of todos so your state might look like this:

```
{
  todosById: {
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      content: 'Do something'
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      content: 'Do another thing'
    }
  }
}
```

When you want an array of all the todos, you create it on the fly whenever you select your state:

```
const selectTodos = (state) => Object.values(state.todosById);
/*
  [{
    id: '1',
    content: 'Do something'
  }, {
    id: '2',
    content: 'Do another thing'
  }]
*/

const selectTodoIds = (state) => Object.keys(state.todosById)
// ['1', '2']
```

Why would you do this? One reason is that it makes it super easy to look things up by ID, as is often needed in the user flow; e.g. show list of things then use selects one of them.

The other reason, applicable in your described situation, is that we can now track each resource's state separately. So each one could have their own `isFetching`, `isSaving`, etc. Or, if you want to guarantee the resource is only every in a single state you could use an enum--but be careful that it truly isn't possible for fetching and saving at the same time!

```
{
  todosById: {
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      content: 'Do something',
      isFetching: false,
      isSaving: false
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      content: 'Do another thing',
      isFetching: false,
      isSaving: false
    }
  }
}

interface Todo {
  id: string;
  content: string;
  isFetching: boolean;
  isSaving: boolean;

  // or using an enum. here are some possibilities:
  enum Status { Fetching, Saving, New, Prestine, Dirty }
  status: Status;
}
```

This also works naturally when your user comes directly to one of the resources. e.g. if they can navigate to a single Todo, you'd populate it in `todosById` and track its status just the same. If you later also load the list of todos, the latest value from the server will be merged into our previously loaded Todo.

When dealing with the creation of a new resource client-side you likely won't already have an ID for it until you save it to the server. In that particular case I have a temporary ID that is generated and used client-side only. e.g. `'tmp-todo-1'`, `'tmp-todo-2'`, etc.

```
{
  todosById: {
    'tmp-todo-1': {
      id: 'tmp-todo-1',
      content: 'A new todo that has never been saved yet',
      status: Status.New
    },
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      content: 'A todo that has been created but has unsaved changes',
      status: Status.Dirty
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      content: 'Do another thing',
      status: Status.Prestine
    }
  }
}
```

### Separate state

Another option for more complex resource request management is to keep it entirely separate and agnostic of the resource its fetching/saving/etc.

Something similar to this:

```
{
  meta: {
    '1': {
      isFetching: false,
      isSaving: false
    },
    '2': {
      isFetching: false,
      isSaving: false
    }
  },
  todosById: {
    '1': {
      id: '1',
      content: 'Do something'
    },
    '2': {
      id: '2',
      content: 'Do another thing'
    }
  }
}
```

This has the benefit of not needing to merge what the resource itself with the client-side only state that isn't included on the server, like what `isFetching` is.

There are many variations of this, some of which people have created libraries around like [redux-resource](https://github.com/jmeas/redux-resource), though I have not used that particular library so I can't speak much on it. I use custom abstractions I've made.

Comment: Very interesting, although the approach is still very verbose it allows for maximum flexibility and granularity. Do you think it would make sense to store a global isFetching flag along the specific status for every entity in case I never load them individually or do you think I should store it with every entity ayway and update it for all every time I load them ?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I was wondering if doing something like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5f970c625be4981eea2d823402e0c72 that is: storing a global isFetching state that is related to every entity would make sense in cases were I don't fetch every item individually and for all the other operations that are "entity specific" I have the progress flags on the entities themselves. Is it more clear now ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a single `isBusy` value in the store? then your reducers toggle this based on `ADD_TODO_..`, `DELETE_TO_DO_..` etc . This assumes you are showing just one busy indicator.

Comment: That's the problem, I want to be able to show more than one spinner at same time. For example: a spinner next to a todo that shows that the todo is being deleted and a spinner next to the "add todo" button that shows that a todo is being added.